# Why is header() stopping page from loading in my dev environment ( MAMP PRO )?

Tags: php, html, header, mamp

I was wondering if anyone had a clue as to why all of sudden on my MAMP PRO why the page will only load up to the `header()` function.

An example of a header call I'm using would be:

```
header('Location: /index_signedIn.php');
exit();
```

I have tried my other sites and it does the same thing.

Any idea would be very helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show us what `header()` calls you are making?

Answer (score 1):

When `header()` calls "suddenly stop working", you might use the [`headers_sent`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.headers-sent.php) function to determine where output has occured before:

```
if (headers_sent($file,$line))
    die("Headers have been sent in $file, line $line");
else {
    header('Location: /index_signedIn.php');
    exit();
}
```

As [jeroen has pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4753106/why-is-header-stopping-page-from-loading-in-my-dev-environment-mamp-pro/4753198#4753198), another PHP file might have triggered outputting of data. It's enough to trigger output flushing if for example an included file begins with `\n\n<?php`.

Comment: @jeroen those are both great points, but I'm suspicious that it's something else because this has never been a problem before....it just started happening when I restarted my MAMP.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess; perhaps you are outputting data to the browser before the call to `heading()`? It could be anything, a space, a new-line after a `?>` tag, etc.

Can you check for messages in the error log?

Comment: @goreSplatter @jeroen those are both great points, but I'm suspicious that it's something else because this has never been a problem before....it just started happening when I restarted my MAMP.